# How to loop through multidimensional array and compare values?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I use the PHP script shown below that takes XML data from the Flickr API and gives out an array, but I don't know how to get the values from this array and do some operations with it.

The array has this format:

```
XmlElement Object
(
    [name] => rsp
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [stat] => ok
        )

    [content] => 
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => XmlElement Object
                (
                    [name] => photos
                    [attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [page] => 1
                            [pages] => 13751
                            [perpage] => 100
                            [total] => 1375086
                        )

                    [content] => 
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => XmlElement Object
                                (
                                    [name] => photo
                                    [attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 25000430521
                                            [owner] => 73422502@N08
                                            [secret] => 19459b26e4
                                            [server] => 1703
                                            [farm] => 2
                                            [title] => Health
                                            [ispublic] => 1
                                            [isfriend] => 0
                                            [isfamily] => 0
                                            [url_m] => https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1703/25000430521_19459b26e4.jpg
                                            [height_m] => 500
                                            [width_m] => 500
                                        )

                                    [content] => 
                                    [children] => 
                                )

                            [1] => XmlElement Object
                                (
                                    [name] => photo
                                    [attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 35305743196
                                            [owner] => 73422502@N08
                                            [secret] => 9601255217
                                            [server] => 4232
                                            [farm] => 5
                                            [title] => Health
                                            [ispublic] => 1
                                            [isfriend] => 0
                                            [isfamily] => 0
                                            [url_m] => https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4232/35305743196_9601255217.jpg
                                            [height_m] => 333
                                            [width_m] => 500
                                        )

                                    [content] => 
                                    [children] => 
                                )
```

Here is what I try to accomplish:

I try to use these 2 values
´[height_m] => 333 [width_m] => 500´

and use the if construct..

```
 if (**width_m** / **height_m** >= 1.25 ) { 
 echo "<img src=" **url_m** " width="100">;
 }
 else {
 echo "<img src=" **url_m** " width="50">;
 }
```

How do I get this construct in a for each loop?

The code that generates the array comes from an awesome user at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php)

```
class XmlElement {
  var $name;
  var $attributes;
  var $content;
  var $children;
};

function xml_to_object($xml) {
  $parser = xml_parser_create();
  xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
  xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
  xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $tags);
  xml_parser_free($parser);

  $elements = array();  // the currently filling [child] XmlElement array
  $stack = array();
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $index = count($elements);
    if ($tag['type'] == "complete" || $tag['type'] == "open") {
      $elements[$index] = new XmlElement;
      $elements[$index]->name = $tag['tag'];
      $elements[$index]->attributes = $tag['attributes'];
      $elements[$index]->content = $tag['value'];
      if ($tag['type'] == "open") {  // push
        $elements[$index]->children = array();
        $stack[count($stack)] = &$elements;
        $elements = &$elements[$index]->children;
      }
    }
    if ($tag['type'] == "close") {  // pop
      $elements = &$stack[count($stack) - 1];
      unset($stack[count($stack) - 1]);
    }
  }
  return $elements[0];  // the single top-level element
}
```

Comment: It would probably be quicker if you used the original XML and didn't bother converting it an array.  If you post the original XML then perhaps it would help.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if you got the help you needed. That will mark the question as answered and help keep Stack Overflow nice and clean. If none of the answers worked for you and you have found another solution then submit it as an answer and mark it correct.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it but I did not quite know how to use this code. There are things that I do understand about php already, but I think this is a little bit over beginner level. I will add the code to my question. Sometimes I think its awesome how quick new things can be learned and applied in php but I think I was missing something here,..

Comment: Please look at his again @Fabian

Comment: @B.Richardson That's some neat code and as expected it creates the XmlElement object that you have shown us in the first code block. However, it does not shed any new light on your question. Have you tried any of the answers you've received? Did they not work for you? Did you get errors? Tell us what went wrong and we might be able to help.

Comment: What is the variable name of XMLElement Object in this case? Is it  $XML? @Fabian thanks

Comment: @B.Richardson Oh, I see. That is not clear from the code you have posted, but simply put, you decide for yourself what the name is. Since the function you are using to create the XmlElement structure has a return value, you use it by defining a variable yourself and setting the content of that variable to be whatever is returned by the function, like this: ```$myXML = xml_to_object($xml);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach I can conceive (change "$Object" to the variable name of your XMLElement Object):

```
foreach($Object->children[0]->children as $child) {
    if ($child->attributes['width_m'] / $child->attributes['height_m'] >= 1.25 ) { 
        echo "<img src=" . $child->attributes['url_m'] . " width="100">;
    }
    else {
        echo "<img src=" . $child->attributes['url_m'] . " width="50">;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a foreach loop but it will essentiall do the same thing:

```
$allImageHtml = array_map(function($photoData){
    $width = ($photoData->attributes['width_m'] / $photoData->attributes['height_m']) >= 1.25 ?100:50;
    return "<img src='{$child->attributes['url_m']} width='{$width}'/>";
}, $Object->children[0]->children);

echo implode('<!-- Separator HTML. (ie: br) -->', $allImageHtml);
```

Alternatively if you would prefer a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($Object->children[0]->children as $photoData){
    $width = ($photoData->attributes['width_m'] / $photoData->attributes['height_m']) >= 1.25 ? 100: 50;
    $spacer = "<!-- Separator HTML. (ie: br) -->";
    echo "<img src='{$child->attributes['url_m']} width='{$width}'/>{$spacer}";
}
```